# Global View and Local View in Android App

Tags: java, android

I just wrote a simple Android app with a LinearLayout only. I use this LinearLayout as **property** of class and as a **local object** of method (for example in onCreate method).

*First case: LinearLayout as a property*

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout root = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(root);
    }
}
```

*Second case: LinearLayout as a object of method*

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout root = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(root);
    }
}
```

In both cases, there is no error. However, when I run on simulator or device, the first case ran to error as below. Why? I think this issue is caused by `getApplicationContext` method. The context of this method hasn't initialized yet until the `onCreate` method is called. Is this true?

[image]

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: localglobal, PID: 6701
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{localglobal/localglobal.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.Context
>   android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
>   reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context
>   android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
>   reference
>                         at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:105)
>                         at localglobal.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:9)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Comment: post `stack trace` here

Comment: `I think this issue is caused by getApplicationContext method. The context of this method hasn't initialized yet until the onCreate method is called. Is this true?` yes it is true

Comment: Did you try setting layout params for LinearLayout? Also use MainActivity.this instead of getApplicationContext() and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a Context object is first initialized, it isn't ready to be used as a Context yet, and most of its methods will return `null`. The Activity class is an extension of the Context class, so it follows the same rules.

When you have:

```
LinearLayout root = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
```

as a global variable, Java will attempt to initialize your LinearLayout while your MainActivity is initializing, *before* the Context has been attached or prepared. `getApplicationContext()` is likely returning `null`, although even passing `this` would cause errors, since Views use the Context during initialization to call `getResources()`, which will also be null at that point.

That's why Android provides the `onCreate()` method. This method is only called once the Context has been attached and is ready for use.

If you want a global LinearLayout variable, do this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LinearLayout root;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        root = new LinearLayout(this);
        setContentView(root);
    }
}
```

However, this isn't the way Android is meant to really work. Instead, you should create a layout XML (under `/res/layouts/`, Android Studio should have done this for you anyway), where you define your layout in XML, and give your Views ids. Then in your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LinearLayout root;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);
        root = findViewById(R.id.whatever_id_you_gave_your_linearlayout_in_xml);
    }
}
```

Your layout XML might look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/whatever_id_you_gave_your_linearlayout_in_xml"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/some_other_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/a_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! I also think I you said. I tried to wrote the code as you wrote: declare in class, but initialize in `onCreate`. So, it works normally.

Actually, I don't use it for Layout, I create some other components, such as `Button`, `TextView` as properties and initialized there (not in `onCreate`). So, the program ran to same error. I just cannot find any documentation to say about that.

Comment: Again, you should be using a layout XML if you have multiple components. Android will take care of positioning and inflating them for you.